# transactions in sesame 2 with application/x-rdftransaction mime-type

Tags: sesame

I need to have transactional updates in my sesame store. I understand that I need to send the request to statements endpoint as a POST request with application/x-rdftransaction mime type.

But its not very well documented. Could you please provide a full example on how the transaction request would like in REST.

Comment: I'd suggest you use SPARQL update sequences instead. The Sesame XML transaction format is not a robust way to talk to Sesame (in fact there are plans to remove it from the framework altogether, now that SPARQL supports updates).

Comment: just to make sure.....update is an atomic operation in sesame/sparql? I was looking at http://www.w3.org/wiki/SparqlUpdateLanguage and it seems an atomic operation

Comment: Yes, it is an atomic operation.